# Is there a chat room for discussing stack overflow chat rooms?

Tags: discussion, chat

Stack Overflow "chat rooms" are (I believe!) a relatively new concept.   Likely there are all sorts of interesting discussions to be had about how well they are working and how they could be improved, that are not so suited to a Q&A format like meta.... but would be very well suited to a chat room.

I tried to search for such a chat room, but I didn't come up with anything, so I made one.

I made one because it seems like a logical thing to have: a place to discuss features, issues etc before making feature requests here in meta (I guess that's where such a thing would be done?)

So -  I thought it worth checking that there isn't already one that I missed, or whether there's some decent name that it should have in line with any naming convention etc that I'm not aware of... hence this question: is there one already?   (And sub question - what should one be named).

Comment: So you want meta.chat? :)

Comment: I understand that downvotes in meta mean that the person thinks this is not a good idea.   It would be kind of nice to get a reply saying why.   Should I just post my question, like "why can't we type code reliably into chat windows" in meta?

Comment: It could be disagreement or maybe they didn't think your question was unclear or was not well research, or because they don't like your profile picture, or they had a bad day.  If you asked me to guess, it might be "unclear" because it isn't really all that clear what you are asking?  Are you looking for a special chat room to discuss features for chat?

Comment: Thx, clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is any chat room specifically to discuss what to discuss on meta and I think that would be a bit redundant and make meta almost obsolete. The point of meta is to discuss feature-requests, etc... so I don't think there is a need to have a place to discuss discussing these things. You put it on here then more people will see it and you won't have the same issues discussed multiple times.

However, I am a daily member of *the* Android room and sometimes we discuss things in there that we are considering putting on meta. This seems to work because A) it isn't something that happens often or is a main topic of the room B) we person thinking about posting may get comments from other members of the room which makes them rethink it. However, having a chat *just* for discussing what to put on here seems redundant to me. If you think it's a good idea then post it. So, you may see if there is a room that is based on a language, etc... that you like and you could discuss proposals in there (depending on the room and it's rules/etiquette).

**Edit**

After reading your edited post and comment, it seems you mean a place to discuss enhancements/changes to chat rooms themselves. This is still fine to do on meta, AFAIK. You don't need to have a fully functioning out-of-the-box and ready to implement idea to post here. Obviously, the more details and information you can give about your idea will help. But having a decent idea that needs some other suggestions can be posted here (hence the discussion tag).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Drat - tt seems my question is still not clear, though your answer might apply to it anyhow.  But just to be sure: I was not suggesting to talk in general about what to put in meta.   I was wanting to talk about features of chat rooms.   It seems that this has to be done as a feature request in meta at the moment - a feature request is something that has to be already thought through.  That thinking could take place in discussion in a chat room.   That's what I'm looking for....

Comment: See my edit. I think that should solve your issue.